# PHP8, how to write comments in attributes?

Tags: php, php-8

I am migrating from annotations to attributes, but I have a doubt.
How should I write comments to my methods, to explain their functionality?

Should I combine annotations and attributes, like this?

```
/**
 * This route does this and that.
 */
#[Route('/my/route/', name:'my_route')]
public function myRoute(): Response
```

But it's ugly. Or opposite, even uglier:

```
#[Route('/my/route/', name:'my_route')]
/**
 * This route does this and that.
 */
public function myRoute(): Response
```

Or should I put them with an hashtag? But it's not parsed correctly by IDEs (I don't see that description when I mouseover the method)

```
# This method does this and that
#[Route('/my/route/', name:'my_route')]
public function myRoute(): Response
```

I know this question sounds like an option-based one, but I'm looking if there is an "official" recommended way, I couldn't find anything about this, all the examples about attributes don't have any comment...

Comment: Option 1 looks like the way for me. The IDE correctly parses option 3 because it's not a doc block (which starts with `/**` double asterisks) so it doesn't read them.

Comment: For what it's worth, either order allows both the "Doc Comment" and "Attribute" to show up correctly in reflection: https://3v4l.org/YtVTQ vs https://3v4l.org/cPtI6